# How to install fpdf in anaconda under python 3.7.x?

Tags: python, anaconda, fpdf, python-3.7

I have some statistical results wanted to export to PDF format, I search this website and seems using FPDF is a good choice.

I am using Anaconda under windows 10 and in Anaconda Prompt I typed the codes as illustrated in [Anaconda clouds](https://anaconda.org/foxbms/fpdf):

```
conda install -c foxbms fpdf
```

But an error occurs, which says:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - fpdf -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package wincertstore conflicts for:
fpdf -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> wincertstore[version='>=0.2']
Package certifi conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
fpdf -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26|>=2017.4.17']
Package wheel conflicts for:
fpdf -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> wheel
python=3.7 -> pip -> wheel
Package setuptools conflicts for:
fpdf -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> setuptools
python=3.7 -> pip -> setuptools
Package pip conflicts for:
fpdf -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip
python=3.7 -> pip
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=3.7 -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
fpdf -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> requests -> urllib3[version='>=1.21.1,<1.24'] -> cryptography[version='>=1.3.4'] -> openssl[version='>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a'] -> ca-certificates
Package msgpack-python conflicts for:
fpdf -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pip -> cachecontrol -> msgpack-python
```

Is it because my 3.7.4 python version is higher than required 3.6?

And if their is any solution to install FPDF?

Thanks. And I appologize if this is a silly question.

Comment: Yes. This line `python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']` means that the package only supports Python 3.6. There are plenty of Python packages that handle pdf export, I'm sure you can find an alternative.

Comment: @orangeInk Thanks, I will try to find some other packages.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python version `Python 3.7.1` and I typed this command into the Anaconda command prompt to install `FPDF`:

```
pip3 install fpdf
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use pip for that, simply type

```
pip install fpdf2
```

[fpdf2](https://pypi.org/project/fpdf2/) is a fork of fpdf, supports Python 3.6+ and is still in development.